# SVN merging changes to externals prop

Tags: svn, merge, svn-externals

Saving for prosperity as I didn't find anything through the google.

While starting up a project I needed to move some svn:externals properties around. Specifically a couple folders deeper than it currently was. All seemed to be working, `svn propdel svn:externals foldername` and propadd where I wanted it to the external SVN repo I wanted.  Everything works, I commit to my branch and then try to merge into trunk. When I got this:

```
svn: E200007: Can't schedule the working copy at '/rootfolder/buildfolder' from repository 'https://repo/Common' with uuid '$number' for addition under a working copy from repository 'svn+ssh://repo/Common' with uuid '$number'.
```

Which is apparently just not done as there's nothing online talking about this exact problem. It blocked merge which blocked development.

What's up?

Comment: Thank you for storing this for later, it has saved me from hours of docs reading.

Answer (score 3):

During a merge SVN looks elsewhere for external folders as it's someone else's problem, so it has a hard time catching that there was a change to the externals property itself.   Or by whatever means, it couldn't even start to resolve the merge issue.

You can  delete the svn prop in your trunk to force it to take the merge

- `svn propdel svn:externals foldername`,  just like you did in the branch
- `svn update`
- merge
- `svn update` again to pull in the external files.

Then you're all set for a commit.